# Why does this function work with min, but not without?

Tags: python, recursion, min

```
def edDistRecursive(a,b):
    #print(a, 'a')
    #print(b,'b')

    if len(a) == 0:
        return len(b)

    if len(b)==0:
        return len(a)



    delta = 1 if a[-1] != b[-1] else 0
    return min(edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1]) + delta,   edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b)+1,  edDistRecursive(a, b[:-1]) +1)
```

`edDistRecursive('actor','racto')`

`2`

However, if I run it without `min`,

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

This is an algorithm used in genetics (approximate matching), to determine how many edits are needed to match `a` and `b`. I thought if I ran it without min I would be able to see how many edits each function was producing.

EDIT:  I think I understand the ouput is a tuple but I'm a little confused as well.
If I remove the other two functions are simplify the function like this

```
def edDistRecursive(a,b):
    #print(a, 'a')
    #print(b,'b')

    if len(a) == 0:
        return len(b)

    if len(b)==0:
        return len(a)



    delta = 1 if a[-1] != b[-1] else 0
    return edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1]) + delta 


edDistRecursive('actor','racto')  returns a value of  5.
```

Why is it that delta can be added here without any problems?

Another example is this below

```
def sum(x,y):
    x =3
    y =2

    return x+y, y


(sum(2,3))
```

Even something like this, whose output is a tuple, has no problem with the addition operation to one of its elements.

In my function above, the value delta, or +1 are being added to a tuple and that's what's bringing up the error, it seems But the int values are not being added to the entire tuple.In fact each element of the tuple consists of (function + int). So I don't see how I'm adding to the tuple, when an element of the tuple itself is (function + int).

`x,y,z = edDistRecursive('actor','racto')`   seems to be leading to the same error as well.

I thought that by adding brackets to each function  `((edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1]) + delta),   (edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b)+1), (edDistRecursive(a, b[:-1]) +1))`,

Python would be able to see each element of the tuple as `function + int`, but I'm running into the same error.

Is there a way to get the value of each function, which is my original goal?

Comment: `min` is a function, and the comma separated list in parens are the arguments to that function.  It will return one of those ints. Without `min`, the comma separated list in parens is a tuple, and you can't add an into to a tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider what happens at the second to lowest (see edit below) level of the recursion, the recursive call to, say, `edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1])` will return a tuple of ints.  When the program attempts to concatenate the `delta` value (which is an int) to this tuple, the error gets thrown.  By using min, you guarantee that the return type is always the same and compatible with your implementation.

EDIT:  Let's step through an example so that we can more directly view what's going on.  For this example, let us *not* use min so that we can see where the issue arises.

To make the example simple, assume that we start with

```
edDistRecursive(['x','k','z'], ['y','e','d'])
```

At some point in doing the recursive calls (namely after doing the first recursive call in every return statement), we will reach

```
edDistRecursive(['x'], ['y'])
```

This is what I meant by "the very lowest level of the recursion", but it's really the "second to last level", since we are *about* to reach the base cases.

So a = ['x'] and b = ['y'].  We now step into the function and check the first two ifs:
* Is len(a) == 0? No.
* Is len(b) == 0? No.
* Calculate delta = 1
* `return edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1]) + delta,`
  `edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b) + 1,`
  `edDistRecursive(a, b[:-1]) + 1`

Now Python will evaluate the first recursive call, since it must do so before it can actually return something.

The first recursive call will be `edDistRecursive([], [])`.  Let's now see what happens:
* Is len(a) == 0? Yes, base case reached - return len(b) = 0

So now we go back up one level, to the return statement from before:
`return 0 + 1, edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b) + 1, edDistRecursive(a, b[:-1]) + 1`

`edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b)` will evaluate to `edDistRecursive([], ['y'])`.
Let's check that call out now:
* Is len(a) == 0? Yes, base case reached - return len(b) = 1

Go back up to the return statement again:
`return 0 + 1, 1 + 1, edDistRecursive(a, b[:-1])`

`edDistRecursive(a, b[:-1])` will evaluate to `edDistRecursive(['x'], [])`.
This is the last call to evaluate at this level:
* Is len(a) == 0? No.
* Is len(b) == 0? Yes - return len(a) = 1

Once more, let's look at the return statement, which can now actually be returned:
`return 1, 2, 1 + 1`

OK, so the result from the recursive call we dove into is the tuple `(1, 2, 2)`.
When this gets returned to the `edDistRecursive` that called it (say `edDistRecursive(['x','k'], ['y','e'])`), that's when the exception gets raised:

```
return (1, 2, 2) + delta, edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b) + 1, ...
       |---------------|
       this will raise the exception
```

I highly recommend that you draw out an example similar to this one and examine all of the recursive steps.  Try it without using min, and then try it with min - you should notice a difference in what gets returned at certain levels.

Comment: `edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1])` on its own works fine.

Comment: `edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1])+ delta` on its own seems to works fine though.

Comment: And it's not returning a tuple of ints. It's returning one value.

Comment: But if you remove the call to min then the first time (will happen after one of the two base cases is reached) you get a result back from a recursive call, it will return a tuple of three values.  This is when you run into the error.  With the call to min, the method will indeed return one value - the minimum of the three values that would have been returned as a tuple otherwise.

Comment: You are confusing me.   `edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1])` is a only one output. 
And only returning one value.   Unless you are talking about all three recursive outputs.

Comment: I have added some more explanation - hope it clears up your confusion.

Comment: I think I got it. When` edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1])+ delta` recurses(?), it's actually forcing the other two functions to be invoked (by the return), and the delta is supposed to be added to  edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1]), which in a sense would mean that it has to be added to the other two functions as well that were invoked during the edDistRecursive.

I drew out most of it, but each recursion evokes 3 functions, and each of those 3 functions draw out 3 each. So it gets messy quick. 

Thank you so much for taking the time to explain everything.

Comment: Awesome!  Really glad to hear that you understood it.  Yeah, drawing out recursion trees can be pretty labor-intensive...but every once and a while it really helps to visualize the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear what "if I run it without `min`" means, exactly, but here's the obvious take on it:  a statement of the form

```
return min(x, y, z)
```

returns whichever one of `x`, `y`, and `z` is smallest, but a statement of the form

```
return x, y, z
```

returns the tuple with three elements `(x, y, z)`.

Is it that simple?

### Ponder

English isn't working here ;-)  Look at a much simpler example, which has exactly the same kind of problem:

```
def f(n):
    if n < 5:
        return n + 1
    return min(f(n // 2) + 1, f(n // 3) + 7)
```

Then, e.g.,

```
>>> f(100)
9
```

Now take away `min`:

```
def f(n):
    if n < 5:
        return n + 1
    return (f(n // 2) + 1, f(n // 3) + 7)
```

Then:

```
>>> f(100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

Can only suggest you work this line by line until the light turns on.  Your original question should become crystal clear then.

Comment: Does a function with multiples values always return as a tuple? Usually, I'm able to  assign the three values to three variables but in this that's also leading to errors.  Thank you.

Comment: Don't know what "function with multiple values" means.  `return x` or `return (x)` return whatever `x` is.  `return x,` or `return (x,)` return a tuple with the single element `x`.  `return x, y` or `return (x, y)` return a tuple with two elements.  Etc.  It's the comma that constructs a tuple, not the parentheses.  It appears that your mental model is more complicated than the truth - so simplify it ;-)

Comment: Hi Tim.Thanks for the reply. Even if my output is a Tuple, my ` + delta ` operation is being applied to one element of the tuple. Why does this work but not my function above?

`def sum(x,y):
    x =3
    y =2
    
    return x+1, y`

Comment: Sorry, but at this point i have no idea what you're asking anymore.  `return x+1, y` returns the 2-tuple `(x+1, y)`, which is simply `(4, 2)` given `x=3` and `y=2`.  If you go on to, e.g., do `42 + sum(3, 2)`, then you'll get an error, because the int `42` cannot be added to the tuple `(4, 2)`.

Comment: `42 + sum(3, 2)`   results in an error, because the ouput is a (4,2) right? 

`edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1]) + delta` doesn't result in an error though    (when I remove the other 2 recursive functions) ?  I"m getting a result of 5.
The output seems to be always `None`  or an an `int.`

Now when I return all three functions, I'm assuming your are saying, that's when the output is a tuple? 

`edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1]) + delta ,(edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b)+1 ),( edDistRecursive(a, b[:-1]) +1)`

If so, then my operations aren't being done to the whole tuple.

Comment: They are being done to each element of the tuple, just as I showcased with the  `def sum` function.  That's what's confusing me.   I really hope you can understand what's confusing.

Comment: Okay, I finally figured out what I was confused about.
This post cleared up my confusion. 

https://python-forum.io/Thread-Can-t-understand-the-output-of-this-recursion-function

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs in sections like the following:

`edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1]) + delta`

Remember that `delta` is a number. You can only add a number to a number. However, if a previous call to `edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1])` returns a tuple (lets say `(1,2,3)`) then, you are trying to do the computation:

`(1,2,3) + delta`

Which is an error.

Comment: edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1]) by itself is only returning one integer at the end of the recursion. However if delta is added, it returns the value 5(so the recursion must occur 5 times) How is it that delta being added to a recursive function that no value?

Comment: The recursive function is _always_ returning a value. Either `len(a)`, or `len(b)` or `edDistRecursive(a[:-1], b[:-1]) + delta`, each of which happens to be a number.